# Let $d(n)$ the number of representation of $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$, what is the order of $d(n)$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $d(n)$ the number of representation of $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$ ($n, x, y$ are positive integers, $x \le y$). For example, $d(2) = 2$, because there are two solutions, $(x, y) = (3, 6), (4, 4)$.

What is smallest function $f(n)$ that satisfies $d(n) \le O(f(n))$?

Comment: Obviously, you assume that $x, y$ are positive integers, otherwise, $(1,-2)$ would be a solution for $n=2$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry, I was intended these are positive integers. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that the the number of positive solution pairs $(x,y)$ to the equation 
$$
\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}
$$
is equal to $\tau(n^2)=d(n^2)$, i.e., to the number of positive divisors of $n^2$, see for example [here](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-19/NNTDM-19-2-15-25.pdf). The asymptotics for $\tau(n)$ now gives the answer, e.g., 
$$\displaystyle \tau(n) \leq n^{O( 1/ \log \log n)} = \exp( O( \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} ) ).$$
For a discussion see [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/).

Comment: That's true only if you count $(3,6)$ and $(6,3)$ as different solutions for $n=2$, the OP doesn't ($\tau(2^2)=3$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry for I didn't added constraint $x \le y$, but the answer don't change because I am asking order and if the answer multiply by 2 the order don't change.